# Why doesn't this script succeed from crontab as it does when manually run?

Tags: cron, cp, non-root-user, doas

This script works when executed with `doas ./backup_cron_root.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/bin/crontab -l> "/tmp/cron.$(whoami).$(hostname)" && /bin/date>>"/tmp/cron.$(whoami).$(hostname)" &&
/usr/bin/doas -u joanna /usr/bin/cp -f "/tmp/cron.$(whoami).$(hostname)" "/home/joanna/pCloudDrive/backups" &&
/usr/bin/rm "/tmp/cron.$(whoami).$(hostname)"
```

where `./backup_cron_root.sh` is the name of the script.
When the same script is scheduled as a cronjob with
`doas crontab -e` and `* * * * * /home/joanna/backup_cron_root.sh >/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1`
it creates `/tmp/cron.root.joanna-ONE-AMD-M4` which is owned by `root`
but for some reason it does not succeed in copying it to `/home/joanna/pCloudDrive/backups`. Why so?
Why doesn't this script succeed from crontab as it does when manually run?

The content of my `/etc/doas.conf` is

```
permit joanna as root
permit root as joanna
```

The following is my tail of `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`:

```
Feb 26 17:17:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747796]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 26 17:17:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747797]: (root) CMD (/home/joanna/backup_cron_root.sh)
Feb 26 17:17:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747792]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:17:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747791]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:17:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747794]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:17:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747793]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:17:22 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[747795]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:18:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[751555]: (root) CMD (/home/joanna/backup_cron_root.sh)
Feb 26 17:18:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[751551]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:18:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[751550]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:18:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[751553]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:18:01 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[751552]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Feb 26 17:18:22 joanna-ONE-AMD-M4 CRON[751554]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

The content of `/tmp/cronjob.log` is

```
doas: Authentication failed
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the cron log file or mailed to root? Also, you don't seem to permit root change to joanna without giving a password.

Comment: @Kusalananda Included the log in response to your comment. Can the password requirement for `/usr/bin/doas -u jim /usr/bin/cp -f "/tmp/cron.$(whoami).$(hostname)" "/home/jim/pCloudDrive/backups"` be the culprit?

Comment: Yes, that could be the culprit.  Since you don't have local mail delivery configured on the system and the cron daemon does not show the actual errors, you should redirect all script output to some log file. Do this by adding `>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` after the command in the schedule, then look at the `/tmp/cronjob.log` file when the job has been run. This should give you more information about what may have gone wrong.

Comment: @Kusalananda I further modified my question providing more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you do not allow the root user to switch to the `joanna` user without a password in your `doas` configuration.

You do this with the `nopass` option in the `doas.conf` file:

```
permit nopass root
```

(It makes little sense to stop the root user from using `doas` to change to other users, so I removed the `as joanna` bit.)

You also have the option of using `su` in place of `doas`:

```bash
su joanna -c 'cp "$1" ~/pCloudDrive/backups/" sh "$tmpfile"
```

Alternatively, copy the file as root and change ownership of it with `chown` afterwards.

---

Your script may also be simplified somewhat:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

tmpfile=/tmp/crontab.$(whoami).$(hostname)

{ crontab -l; date; } >"$tmpfile"

doas -u joanna cp "$tmpfile" ~joanna/pCloudDrive/backups/
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

I've deleted the excessive use of absolute pathnames. If `/usr/bin` and `/bin` are not in `$PATH` when this script is executed from cron, then something's broken in your setup.

I've also assigned the output filename to a variable, which means we don't have to execute `whoami` and `hostname` each and every time we need to refer to it.

I have removed the conditional execution of every command, opting to let the script continue with cleaning up the temporary directory instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `cp: cannot stat '/tmp/tmp.n5bvhyZ2be/crontab.root.joanna-ONE-AMD-M4': Permission denied` gets logged whereas if I substitite `doas -u joanna cp "$tmpfile" /home/joanna/pCloudDrive/backups/` with `doas -u joanna /usr/bin/cp "/tmp/cron.$(whoami).$(hostname)" "/home/joanna/pCloudDrive/backups"` then all is well.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ah, the temporary directory is being created usable only by root, I see (and I did not take that into consideration). And your "fix" uses an old file from a previous run of your old code (don't do that). I'll sort out the code in my answer in a very short time. (Done now)